# How do I know when a word with "ch" is pronounced hard or softly?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm hard-of-hearing, so when I read, I pronounce things phonetically because I don't hear a lot of soft sounds (like /sh/). To my surprise over the years, I've been continuously corrected on words that have a "ch" sound in them.

For example, "parachute" is pronounced "para shoot" \ˈper-ə-ˌshüt, ˈpa-rə-\ and not "para chewt".

Are there any indicators of when I would use a hard "ch" sound (like in "choose")?

Comment: I'm not aware of any hard and fast rules on this. I think it's just practice.

Comment: Note that *ch* is also sometimes pronounced as *k*, in words of Greek or Hebrew origin.

Comment: Also 'loch' and other words from Gaelic use a 'k'-like sound - a guttural 'kh'.

Comment: There are regional differences in the pronunciation of 'schedule' (like 'school' or like 'sheep').

Comment: Don't forget the silent ch as in yacht. I know there are some more silent ch words, but can't think of any right now.

Comment: You have simply to learn it by looking up words where you are in doubt.  "To choose" is not pronounced with /k/ (hard ch),  but with the chair-sound.

Comment: @quay drachm, chthonian It's very embarrassing to pronounce the silent ch in fuchsia. I think the ch in schism is silent, but I find I am in the vast minority, if there is such a thing.

Comment: Don't forget choir - a genuine hard 'k' sound

Answer (score 16):

There is no hard-and-fast rule to indicate when ch is hard or soft, unfortunately.

The main difference is in the origin of the word. English is a melting pot of many different languages: Latin, French, German, Scandinavian languages, you name it. In general, words originating from French will have a soft ch:

> Parachute, cache, attache

Words originating from Germanic languages will have a hard ch:

> Church, bench

However, even this isn't foolproof because many French-origin words have been hardened:

> Bachelor, channel, charm

I would say that there are considerably more hard ch words than there are soft.

Comment: There is an even harder ch, in words like psychic and Bach, which is almost a "k" sound, which, as RegDwight points out above, is of Hebrew or Greek origin.

Comment: @Andy F: indeed, I think this is two slightly different things.  There's the velar fricative *ch* in a few Scots words and German proper names, like *loch* and *Bach*, which is as you say almost but not quite a "k" sound.  But then there's the *ch* in words of Greek origin like *psychic* and *synchronised*, which in the original Greek was like the *Bach* / *loch* velar fricative, but which in English is now a *k* sound - no 'almost' about it.  Words from Hebrew are more variable: "cherub" goes like "charm", "challah" goes like "Bach", "chutzpah" varies depending on whom you talk to.

Comment: Actually in Classical Greek 'χ' ('chi') was pronounced like "c" in "cat" (aspirated, in contrast to 'κ' ('kappa') which was unaspirated like "c" in "scat"). It was only later that the Greek aspirates became lenited to fricatives.

Comment: It depends on when the words entered English, as well as where from. French words that were naturalised centuries ago generally have 'ch' = /tʃ/ ('charity'), while those that have come in in the last hundred years often have /ʃ/ ('parachute'). Similarly, Hebrew words that came with the Bible through Greek, Latin and French may have /tʃ/ ('cherub'), whereas recent imports tend to have /x/ ('challah').

Comment: There may not be many "hard-and-fast rules", but I suspect you've touched on one yourself - *attach/attache = hard/soft*. I can't think offhand of any words ending *[vowel] + ch + e* that aren't "soft". Come to that, I can't think of any with *[consonant]* instead of *[vowel]* there. But even if there *are* exceptions, I'm sure it's a reasonably reliable rule.

Answer (score -1):

I just found a great website I think will you help you out a lot, explaining the rules for when to pronounce 'ch' as a hard or soft c:

http://www.brighthubeducation.com/english-homework-help/39405-learn-the-correct-pronunciation-of-the-english-letter-c/

Comment: Due to link rot it is greatly preferred that you provide the requested information in the body of your answer rather than providing a bare link.

Comment: The link says "sometimes" and "sometimes". This is not the most useful advice.