# Why is "chore" pronounced differently from the "chore" in "choreography"?

Tags: pronunciation

How come the word "chore" is pronounced like it is, when the word "choreography", which has the same initial letter combination, is pronounced differently? Is there a phonetical rule to explain this?

Comment: Related: [How do I know when a word with “ch” is prounounced hard or softly?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10763/how-do-i-know-when-a-word-with-ch-is-prounounced-hard-or-softly)

Answer (score 16):

Because of etymology: *chore* is written in the *New Oxford American Dictionary* as **“(originally dialect and U.S.): variant of obsolete char or chare (see charwoman)”**, which the same pronunciation as the modern verb *char*. It [ultimately comes](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chore) from Middle English *cherre* (odd job), from Old English *cerr*, *cierr* (turn, occasion).

*Choreography*, like *chorus*, *choir*, [all ultimately come](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chorus) from the Latin *chorus* (pronounced *k-*) and its derivatives, from Greek *khoros* (dance).

Comment: +1 Note that *choros* is not a verb but a noun.

Answer (score 3):

It is a coincidence, because "chore" has different etymologies.
 In general, "ch" sounds like a "k" in words originating from Greek; 
"choreo" from "choreography" derives from the Greek "khoros" (band of dancers or singers, dance, dancing ground).

"ch" has usually one of the three pronunciations:  tʃ(porch), k(chaos) or ʃ (machine)

Related question: [How do I know when a word with *ch* is pronounced hard or softly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10763/how-do-i-know-when-a-word-with-ch-is-prounounced-hard-or-softly)

Comment: "ch" also has a velar fricative pronunciation [x] for some English speakers, for example in *loch*.

Comment: @Henry I know, that's why I said "usually"; "ch" has other rare pronunciations