# Pronunciation Rules for Ch words

Tags: pronunciation

Are there any rules for the pronunciation of Ch words. In words like, for example, chess, chemistry, school, etc. I want to know when should we pronounce 'ch' as "K' and when this has to be pronounced as "tʃ" as in chess.

Comment: Some of them [are discussed here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/111032/15299).

Answer (score 3):

The pronunciation of ⟨ch⟩ as /k/ is generally found in words borrowed from Greek (where the ⟨ch⟩ stands for the Greek letter chi). See Wikipedia: [English words of Greek origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_words_of_Greek_origin):

> *Ch* is pronounced like *k* rather than as in "church": e.g., character, chaos.

It's annoyingly hard to find a non-Wikipedia reference, but this borders on common knowledge.

Loanwords from a few other languages have ⟨ch⟩ pronounced as /k/— for example, *dachshund* (a type of dog; from German) or *loch* ("lake"; from Scots). The sound in the original language was an /x/, not a /k/. Certain German names (or names from other languages transliterated in a German-ish way) are pronounced similarly: *Bach* (German composer), *Friedrich* (common German first name), *Rachmaninoff* (Russian composer; the "scientific" transliteration of his name would be *Rakhmaninov*). There are also a few from Italian, where ⟨ch⟩ does stand for /k/: *bruschetta* (a type of snack with tomatoes on toasted bread; often mispronounced!), *Chianti* (a type of wine), *Pinocchio* (a character from a famous children's book).

You'll also find this question relevant: [How do I know when a word with "ch" is pronounced hard or softly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10763/how-do-i-know-when-a-word-with-ch-is-pronounced-hard-or-softly)

Comment: You might want to edit this to clarify that unlike the German & Scots examples, your examples from Italian do *not* involve the /x/ phoneme in the original language.