# What effect do neighboring vowel-letters have on the pronunciation of the letters "sc" in a word?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, vowels, spelling-pronunciations

Consider these words, with standard pronunciations from Oxford
Dictionaries Online using in the worldwide-standard International
Phonetic Alphabet:

1. *con**sc**ious*, pronounced /ˈkɒnʃəs/
2. *e**sc**hew*, pronounced /ɛsˈtʃuː/ or /ɪsˈtʃuː/
    or according to Merriam-Webster, also /ɛsˈʃuː/ or even /ɛsˈkjuː/.
3. *confi**sc**ate*, pronounced /ˈkɒnfɪskeɪt/
4. *mu**sc**le*, pronounced /ˈmʌsəl/

In *confiscate* and *miscellaneous*, *sc* is preceded and succeeded by
a vowel, yet the sound of *sc* is completely different.

In *conscious* and *eschew*, both have one vowel and one consonant
surrounding *sc*, yet there are multiple pronunciations for *eschew*
and a fixed one for *conscious*.

Do vowels effect the pronunciation of *sc* in a word?

Why does *eschew* have so many
pronunciations? [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eschew) says of it:

> - UK: /ɛsˈtʃuː/, /ɪsˈtʃuː/, /ɪʃˈtʃuː/
> - US: /ɛsˈtʃu/, /ɪsˈtʃu/, /ɛsˈtʃju/
> - US, sometimes proscribed: /ɛˈʃu/, /ɪˈʃu/ or /ɛˈskju/
> - Garner’s *Modern American Usage* prefers /s.tʃ/,
>   proscribes /ʃ/,
>   and does not recognize /sk/.

Comment: Your error is thinking that English pronunciation derives from its spelling. This is false.

Comment: Consider that syllibilization has a strong effect on how the "sc" is pronounced.

Answer (score 3):

Usually only the following vowel letters are relevant, and only for *sc,* not for *sch.*

### Main possible pronunciations of *sc*: /sk/,  /s/ or /ʃ/

In general, "c" in "sc" follows the usual rule for "c": /s/ before "e, i, y" and /k/ before "a, o, u" (the same rule of thumb applies to "g", which  is usually /dʒ/ before "e, i, y" and /g/ before "a, o, u").

The /ʃ/ in "conscious" is because of the coalescent palatalization of /sj/ to /ʃ/. We may also see palatalization of unstressed word-internal /si~sɪ/ to /ʃi~ʃɪ/ when there is another vowel following, as in *fasciation,* which is pronounced either as /ˌfæʃiˈeɪʃən/ or as /ˌfæsiˈeɪʃən/ according to the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=fasciation).

The identity of the preceding vowel/vowel letter is normally not relevant.

Overview of the usual pronunciations:

- *-sc-* = /sk/ before *a, o, u*
- *-sc-* = /s/ before *e, i (y)* in most cases
- *-sc-* = /ʃ/ before *e, i* followed by another vowel letter (only in some cases)

The rules given here have exceptions. Some exceptions are optional, while other exceptions are less optional:

- Some people pronounce *proboscis* with /sk/, but it's also fine, or even preferable, to pronounce it with /s/.
- It seems to me that *fascism* is almost always pronounced with /ʃ/ nowadays, probably due to influence from Italian, where *sc* regularly represents /ʃ/ and not /s/ before *i* or *e* in any context. Still, you can find the pronunciation with /s/ listed in a few dictionaries, like [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fascism) and *O.E.D. Suppl.* (1933) (the modern Oxford English Dictionary mentions this, but doesn't list it as a modern pronunciation).
- The well-known example of *sceptic* (and derived words *sceptical, scepticism* etc.) is invariably pronounced with /sk/, although in the United States the alternative spelling "skeptic" tends to be used, which corresponds more regularly to the pronunciation.

### Main possible pronunciations of *sch*: /sk/, /ʃ/, /stʃ/ (rarely /s/)

The pronunciation of "ch" or "sch" is a quite different matter. The range of pronunciations for "ch" without preceding "s" is covered by [How do I know when a word with "ch" is pronounced hard or softly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10763/how-do-i-know-when-a-word-with-ch-is-pronounced-hard-or-softly)

Basically, there is no useful rule related to vowels for the pronunciation of *sch.* It can be pronounced /sk/, /ʃ/, /stʃ/, /s/ or even /ʃtʃ/ depending on various factors.

- The pronunciation /stʃ/ can normally only occur before a vowel and in the middle of a word, not at the start or end. It seems to only occur in contexts where the /s/ and /tʃ/ can be analyzed as belonging to separate syllables, so perhaps a more detailed transcription of this pronunciation would be /s.tʃ/.
- The consonant cluster /stʃ/ is sometimes pronounced as something similar to [ʃtʃ] because of processes of assimilation. If we set aside this arguably non-phonemic phenomenon, /ʃtʃ/ is a very uncommon pronunciation of *sch*. Some speakers may have /ʃtʃ/ in the word *borsch,* a recent loanword. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/borscht) lists the pronunciation /bɔːʃtʃ/ along with alternative pronunciations /bɔːʃ/ and /bɔːʃt/. (Of course, in American English, a rhotic vowel like [o˞] or [ɔ˞] would be used). Alternative spellings of this word include "borshch", "borscht", "borsht".
- The pronunciation /s/ is very rare. As far as I know, it only occurs in one pronunciation of *schism* (there is also a pronunciation with /sk/), and an obsolete pronunciation of *schedule.*
- I think that *schm* is always pronounced /ʃm/, and *schn-, schr-, schl-* are always pronounced as /ʃn, ʃr, ʃl/ when they come at the start of a word/syllable. In word-medial contexts, there are a few very rare cases where *-schn-* might be pronounced as /sk.n/ (or /s.n/?) in scientific vocabulary (e.g. *[Ischnacanthus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ischnacanthus)*), or where *-schr-* might be pronounced as /s.kr/ (e.g. *[dyschromatopsia](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dyschromatopsia)*).
- Etymology is important: broadly speaking, "sch" is pronounced /sk/ in words from Greek and /ʃ/ in words from German. Words from French are more unpredictable ("eschew" is from French, as is "schedule"). In words from Italian, where "sch" only is used before the letters "e" and "i", "sch" is pronounced as /sk/ (e.g. *scherzo*) ... except for when it isn't (as in one common, but commonly criticized, pronunciation in English of the word *[bruschetta](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bruschetta)*).

Comment: Ah right. You know, I really wish you wouldn't skip the rhotic phoneme in [*borscht*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/borscht), lest it sound like the common pronunciation of Hieronymus Bosch. Statistically, most native speakers of English are rhotic speakers, so the Collins examples are always at least potentially confusing.

Comment: I think you've forgotten /ʃtʃ/ in your list of possible pronunciations of _sch_; you have _borshch_ under /stʃ/, which isn't, as far as I know, one of the possible realisations in that word. And you've left out _eschew_ from that section, where I think it belongs.

Comment: @sumelic It seems to be a one-way street, though (at least to me). /stj/ may be freely realised as [stʃ] or further assimilated to [ʃtʃ], but /ʃtʃ/ does not go the other way. At least I've never heard [bɔːstʃ] and would never say it myself.

Answer (score 0):

And yet, we have "sceptic" (hard c)  (UK spelling) and "sceptre" (soft c).

It's probably safe to generalize that if a word has a Greek stem, but Latinized spelling ("K" was rarely seen in Latin, as "C" always has the hard sound), it's a hard "c".

You can see this in some medical terms, such as "scoliosis"; an accepted variant is "skoliosis"  (Greek, meaning "bending").

Comment: That's not a safe generalization. "Sceptre" is also Latinized Greek.